# How to replace values in entire column with values of other column in same table using content provider?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I want to replace all the values of an entire column(say column 1) with other column (say column 2) of the table using content provider. I have tried multiple options but was unable to find a proper answer.I Know that SET clause can be used but how can i use the SET clause with content provider?
The table is as below:

```
String SOLUTION_CATEGORY_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.DataBaseConstants.LOOK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY_TABLE+"("
                + Constants.DataBaseConstants.LOADER_ID+" NUMERIC AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                +Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOLUTION_CODE+" CHAR(15) NOT NULL,"
                +Constants.DataBaseConstants.CATEGORY_ID+" NUMERIC(6) NOT NULL,"
                +Constants.DataBaseConstants.CATEGORY_NAME+" CHAR,"
                +Constants.DataBaseConstants.DEFAULT_PRODUCTS+" CHAR,"
                +Constants.DataBaseConstants.RECOMMENDED_PRODUCTS+" CHAR,"
                +Constants.DataBaseConstants.LOCAL_DEFAULT+" CHAR,"
                +"CONSTRAINT "+ Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOL_CAT_FK1+" FOREIGN KEY("+Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOLUTION_CODE+")REFERENCES "
                    + Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOLUTION_TABLE+"("+Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOLUTION_CODE+"),"
                +"CONSTRAINT "+ Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOL_CAT_FK2+" PRIMARY KEY ("
                    +Constants.DataBaseConstants.SOLUTION_CODE+","+Constants.DataBaseConstants.CATEGORY_ID+"))";
```

Now i want to replace local default product with default products column.

I know the update query should be something like below:

```
    UPDATE Constants.DataBaseConstants.LOOK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY_TABLE SET Constants.DataBaseConstants.LOCAL_DEFAULT=Constants.DataBaseConstants.DEFAULT_PRODUCTS;
```

But I do not know how to do the same query using content Provider.
What should i send in the arguments of update method(mentioned below) so that the end query is same as above.

```
getContentResolver().update(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_LOOK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY, values, selection, args);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: thanks for responding,I have updated the question with code.